# Dynamically passing value to .click event Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am getting the values of a CSS class using Jquery. When I click the header, I want all of the radio boxes to be marked as checked.
I loop through and find the values, using console.log to check if I am returning the correct values which I am. However when I try to use the function, it will only run it correctly on the first element in the array, where I would like it to apply to all names found in the loop.

```
var skil = $('.Routes');
var skills = new Array();
skil.each(function(i) {
  skills.push($(this).text());
  var Route = '#'+skills[i].replaceAll(' ','');
  console.log(Route);
   $(Route).on('click', function() {
    $(Route).prop("checked", true); //This only performs the function on the First value (in this case for "Purchased")
   });
});
```

Below is an extract of code which runs correctly on both headers. I could replicate this, but there are 17 classes, so ideally I would like to dynamically pass the value in and run through one function if possible.

```
$('#Purchased').on('click', function() {
    $('.Purchased').prop("checked", true);
});

$('#BST').on('click', function() {
    $('BST').prop("checked", true);
});
```

See HTML to build table below

```
<th class="rotate"><div><span class ="Routes" id ="Purchased"> Purchased</span></div></th>
    <th class="rotate"><div><span class ="Routes" id ="BST> BST</span></div></th>

<td bgcolor="#8DB255" class=""> <input type="radio" class="get_value Purchased" name="48215:4G1" id="r8215:4201" value="4:716:597:18.25:200:0:200:NA:PBJB_18223_JTC:375:8215:4:20:2023/09/13:284:284:284:284:284:0::0" checked=""></td>
    <td bgcolor="#8DB255" class=""> <input type="radio" class="get_value BST" name="48215:4G1" id="r8215:4201" value="4:716:597:18.25:200:0:200:NA:PBJB_18223_JTC:375:8215:4:20:2023/09/13:284:284:284:284:284:0::0" checked=""></td>
```

Comment: Give us some HTML so we can test this.

Comment: @disinfor - Added to main post

Comment: @macca4244 try `each2` as opposed to `each`

Comment: @Innovin - I changed skil.each to skil.each2 but it gives an error?

Comment: I have seen the error. will drop an answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use Jquery to add a click handler on the header then use the header text to assign the prop of each table row radio button. Please see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/martlark/hsfrvj90/6/

```
 $('.Routes').on('click', function(e) {
  const radioClass=e.target.innerText.replace(' ', '_');
  $(`.${radioClass}`).prop("checked", true); 
});
```

Comment: @Innovin - Thank you so much, this does exactly what I need it to.

Comment: not my answer @macca4244

Comment: @Martlark also indicate the changes you had to make to the `name` attributes so the OP is aware.

Comment: Oops! Got confused with the different lines. Credit @Martlark, thank you very much. One last thing I needed to do here was to add the line which will replace class names that have multiple spaces in them with the underscores I am generating as part of the code.
radioClass1 = radioClass.replaceAll(' ','_');

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies with a name mismatch.
The ID of your `span` element is `Angle_Plant`

Your html says

```
<th class="rotate"><div><span class ="Routes" id ="Angle_Plant"> Angle Plant</span></div></th>
```

Therefore the result of this `var Route = '#'+skills[i].replaceAll(' ','');` would give you `AnglePlant`

Now you see that `AnglePlant` which you then use as a selector on the next line `$(Route).on('click', function() {` would not match with the HTML element's ID `Angle_Plant`

This is the base reason why it does not work.

Your best bet is to rename your html element's ID to `AnglePlant` as such:

```
<th class="rotate"><div><span class ="Routes" id ="AnglePlant"> Angle Plant</span></div></th>
```

Comment: Sorry I think Angle Plant was a bad example given the space, my main issue is it will only build the .click function once. If I can get that building dynamically given how many instances in the loop there are, then I can work out the naming convention issues and update them. I've updated the main question to show another non spaced element

Comment: My actual code is extremely complex given it is building multiple rows of checks boxes based on the 17 Route headers going horizontally across the top of the page. Hence I'm just trying to simplify the issue to the above.

Comment: One sec. will update my answer in a bit

Comment: @macca4244 just to be sure, you want the input radio element  to be checked when the span element is clicked, correct?

Comment: Yes correct, so if I click Purchased, all the check box rows under the purchased header would be checked, then if I click BST, all those check boxes would would be checked too.

Comment: @macca4244 if you are trying to check multiple radio elements, it won't work in your case because they all bear the same `name` attribute. Only one radio element in a radio elements list with same `name` attribute can be selected at a time. Consider using a checkbox instead of a radio.